# Call lightning Web Component from URL and capture parameter from URL

Tags: salesforce, apex, lwc, salesforce-communities

I want to redirect user from one LWC to another by clicking on URL in experience cloud. Basically, on my first LWC I am showing the list of records retrieved from Apex and then when any row is clicked, I want to pass recordId of that row and redirect to second LWC which will show the record details page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need the second LWC? Can you use the standard record details page instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a Community... sorry, Experience Builder page with that target LWC dropped?

You could use [NavigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) although documentation says communities don't support the `state` property.

On source side try something like

```
/* Assumes the link/button clicked looks like
    <button data-id={acc.Id} onclick={handleClick}>Get details</button>
*/
handleClick(event){
    if(event.currentTarget.dataset.id){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                name: 'MyTargetCommunityPage__c'
            },
            state: {
                id: event.currentTarget.dataset.id
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then on target page's LWC it should be accessible as

```
connectedCallback() {
    if(window.location.href){
        try{
            let url = new URL(window.location.href);
            var id = url.searchParams.get('id');
            if(id){
                this.myId = id;
            }
        } catch(e){
            if(console){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If Navigation gives you hard time you can ditch it and go straight for `window.open('/pagename?id=123', _self);` or something. It's bit annoying that you have 1 set of rules for core Salesforce, 1 for community.

(if you have a namespace - you might need to use `myns__id` in the `state` instead of `id`)

Comment: I also used state property and it worked but I don't know why the documentation has that point.